# Combining same info. columns data from multiple tables into one column of a view

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

I have 2 tables.

```
TABLE_1 ( id, date, column_1 )
TABLE_2 ( id, date, column_1, column_2 )
```

id and date are common for both tables. I want to make a view combining these two.

```
VIEW_LATEST ( index, table_name, id, date)
```

In the view I need an index to identify a particular row separately (not a must). There, I'll have the table name to identify the fact that from where the details of a particular row (id, date) was taken. And, I need to get the information of a particular period only (eg. last week).

Eg.

```
TABLE_1 ([ 1, 2012-01-27 ], [2, 2012-02-01 ])
TABLE_2 ([ 1, 2012-01-20 ], [ 2, 2012-01-31 ])
VIEW_LATEST ([ tbl_1, 2, 2012-02-01 ], [ tbl_2, 2, 2012-01-31 ], [ tbl_1, 1, 2012-01-27])
```

Last week - 2012-01-26 to 2012-02-01, So TABLE_2 first record is not returned in the view.
Ordered by date.

I need to do exactly as mentioned above. I looked for a solution something like this and not found.

Any solution to achieve above scenario is highly appreciated. Further, expect to make a separate table of format VIEW_LATEST to insert data when inserting data to TABLE_1, TABLE_2 to get the latest when required. So, that will be one solution if it's impossible to implement the above scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could UNION the tables together.

For MySQL (no subquery allowed):

```
(SELECT 'Table_1' as tablename, id, date FROM Table_1
WHERE date BETWEEN TO_DATE('20120126', 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20120201', 'YYYYMMDD'))
UNION 
(SELECT 'Table_2' as tablename, id, date FROM Table_2
WHERE date BETWEEN TO_DATE('20120126', 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20120201', 'YYYYMMDD'))
ORDER BY tablename, id, date
```

Result set would be:

```
tablename    id    date
---------    --    -----------
Table_1       1    2012-01-27
Table_2       2    2012-01-31
Table_1       2    2012-02-01
```

Comment: Thank you very much @N West. I tried SELECT and it exactly did as you mentioned. I'm using mysql. There it has specifically mentioned 'The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause. ' in CREATE VIEW statement. It's highly appreciated if someone could suggest a solution to overcome this as I'm primitive in this field.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT src_table, id, the_date
  FROM (SELECT 'TABLE_1' AS src_table, id, the_date
          FROM table_1
          WHERE the_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012-01-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                             AND TO_DATE('2012-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         UNION
         SELECT 'TABLE_2' AS src_table, id, the_date
           FROM table_2
           WHERE the_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012-01-26', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                              AND TO_DATE('2012-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        )
  ORDER BY the_date DESC, id, src_table
```

Replace your dates with SYSDATE-7 or whatever is appropriate

Comment: Thank you very much @Glenn. This works fine in mysql once alias is given to the subquery generated table.I'm using mysql. There it gives an error 'View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause'. In mysql documentation it has specifically mentioned 'The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause. '. It's highly appreciated if someone could suggest a solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: @chandimak I'm not too familiar with mysql, but from what I read, the work around is to to create a separate view for the subquery.